# Processing - accessing proper width and height from a tab

Tags: java, arrays, processing

In my main tab, I use:

```
void setup() {
  fullScreen(1);
  println(positions[0][0]);
};
```

In another tab, I want to create a two-dimensional array and fill it with values that are calculated with the proper width and height dimensions.

```
int[][] positions = {
  {int(width*18/28.), int(height*18/20.)},
  {int(width*6/28.), int(height*18/20.)},
};
```

The expected answer is 972 with a width of 1512 but I get 64 as the width is assigned to the default value 100.

How do I get the proper width and height values in the tab with the array?

Comment: Some more details, for one: what did you expect to get, and what did it print instead? Also, while less important: which version of Processing? 3.x or the new 4? (Also note that  you don't need the int cast: just remove the `.` to make java use integer math. E.g. `width*18/28` instead of `int(width*18/28.)`)

Comment: You are missing both the expected and the actual printed values. On first glance the code looks syntactically correct, but we have no way of knowing if it is semantically correct

Comment: Please put that information [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), rather than your comment. But, while editing: explain _why_ you expect that value. And even better, make this clear by showing the complete [mcve], so that folks can see the values associated with every variable involved.

Comment: (And remember to post syntactically correct code: if folks were to copy-paste what you have in your question right now, they'll get a syntax error because there's no semi-colon at the end of the last line)

Comment: What you get will depend on the types and values of `width` and `height` which you haven't shown.

Comment: @tgdavies width and height default to `100` when left unspecified in Processing (making 64 entirely the expected value)

Comment: "[...] while `println(int(width*18/28.));` gives me 972" is not true in a plain Processing sketch, so you need to show a proper [mcve] if you want to prove that's what you're actually seeing.

Comment: if you're getting 972, that means that your width is somehow set to 1512 for the math to be correct. So if that is the case, the issue is not in the code provided here, but somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything, 64 is the value you should be expecting. `width` and `height` default to 100 if left unspecified, so you're creating a 2d array with the 0,0 element set to `int(width*18/28.)`.

```
100 * 18 / 28 = 1800 / 28 = 64
```

This is doing exactly what it should be.

Comment: The `positions` array is defined in another tab so I guess it doesn't pick the right width and height of my screen. How can I make this array have the right dimensions for width and height?

Comment: no it isn't. Your question shows the 2d array code you're working with, and explains that there's a problem with [0][0]. There isn't, so if that is _not_ your problem: update your post [to properly explain your problem](/help/how-to-ask). Figure out your [mcve], and then write a post that covers the problem that highlights. Don't post code with guide text about that code that isn't actually the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I didn't know that my problem is another one. With your help, I understood it better, thanks!

Comment: that's the whole point of the [mcve] exercise: _always_ do it before posting because it lets you discover what the actual problem is, even if you still can't figure it out once you have your minimal setup.